# AutoFill not picking up my date pattern

Tags: excel, time-series, autofill

I'm tyring to create a time series in the format of `yyyy-mm` (e.g `1950-01`:`1950-12`) for the period `1950-2016`.

I have changed the cell format to this custom setting but still when I try and drag down to `autofill` the next date after `xxxx-12` is `xxxx-13` instead of `01`.

Can anybody advise me on how to get `excel` to recognize this pattern please?

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to format.
Press CTRL+1.
In the Format Cells box, click the number tab.
In the Category list, click custom, and then under Type, type the date format that you want